# QTcpServer with over 300+ connected clients

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, server, architecture

I am trying to build a server using the QTcpServer class. I have it now set up as a single-threaded server.

Main window class has GUI stuff with a push button to start and stop the server.

```
server* start_server new server(this);
start_server->startlisten();
// Starts server from mainwindow
```

Server class:

Listens, signal accept, signal readready

Inside readready, read all bytes to a buffer then process the data to a switch statement, then functions to send data back to the client.

1. Am I OK with 1 main thread recv parsing and sending data back and forth?
2. Should my database be in its own thread too that makes queries and functions to send information back to the server thread?
3. Should I be using QThreadPool instead to set a thread limit to create workers to listen and accept and read data? (Same with database?)

Comment: This really depends on many factors especially the frequency and the length of the messages between the clients and the server, the overhead of serializing and deserializing the messages, and how does the server process these messages. For instance, 300+ connected but mostly idle clients consume a very little amount of CPU cycles after they are connected.

Comment: Your looking around 10 to 1000 bytes of data back and forth every few seconds. There is no idle clients. The serializing and deserializing is base on the QDataStream method. Reading and writing from a structure. Its for a game server.

Comment: I see, well you might want to write a single-threaded prototype first and profile that, then switch to a multi-threaded architecture if needed. Using QThreadPool won't be beneficial here as it doesn't cope well with QObjects, you might however maintain your own thread pool that runs the event loop, and leverage cross-thread signals/slot for communication between your TCP connections and the main thread, But make sure to profile first. Multi-threading brings with it a lot of architectural requirements...